# Can I inject with 2 interfaces with same name in JavaEE 8?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

My project techstack is: JavaEE 8, Wildfly, Jboss
and structure like this:

```
companycontext
  - company
  - workplace
  - employee
  - web (beans.xml here)
```

I have *EmployeeAdapter* interface in both *company* and *workplace* project.
Because CDI will discover every bean in every project so I'll get an error

```
A component named 'EmployeeAdapterImpl' is already defined in this module
```

For now my solution is name like: *ComEmployeeAdapter*, *WorkEmployeeAdapter*...
Can I use something like **@Named**

```
// Implement
@Stateless @Named("company")
EmployeeAdapterImpl implement EmployeeAdapter

// Using
@Inject @Named("company") private EmployeeAdapter

// Implement
@Stateless @Named("workplace")
EmployeeAdapterImpl implement EmployeeAdapter

// Using
@Inject @Named("workplace") private EmployeeAdapter
```

I think it's much better than a rule to name our adapters.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. And no it not working, please notice that I have an EmployeeAdapter interfaces in each project.

Comment: You must name your classes differently e.g. `CompanyEmployeeAdapterImpl` and use it as follows with qualifier: `@Qualifier("CompanyEmployeeAdapterImpl") private EmployeeAdapter a`

Comment: and respectivly the same for the other class

Comment: It work! Hmm, but if I must name class different each project then it not much different with name interface different each project

Comment: Multiple implementations need to be somehow selected and with beans its done that way. even with xml you must do the same

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I must going with a rule to name our adapters then

Comment: By the way, even the most recent WildFly 11.0.0.Final release is still Java EE 7, not Java EE 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an EJB issue, not a CDI issue.

CDI bean type are defined by a fully-qualified class name, so there is no problem having two beans with the same name in different packages.

Since your two `EmployeeAdapterImpl` beans are stateless session beans, the EJB container will generate JNDI names for them. You can see them in the WildFly logs in a message like

```
16:09:39.812 [MSC service thread 1-8] INFO  org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment - WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'Foo' in deployment unit 'deployment "myapp.war"' are as follows:
```

One of the generated names has the form

```
java:module/EmployeeAdapterImpl
```

taking only the simple class name, so this is causing a conflict in your case.

You might want to try the `name` or `mappedName` element of the `@Stateless` annotation.

Comment: This sounds like the true solution to the original post. CDI shouldn't be causing troubles here, but EJB will. Making it generate different JNDI is a way to go.

Comment: With @Stateless(name="CompanyEmployeeAdapterImpl") I still have to make a rule to name. I hoping for something like package with bean name: company.EmployeeAdapterImpl. Thank you for your explanation.